# Eloquent, consulta con un número indeterminado de "where"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

En el siguiente ejemplo tengo una consulta *eloquent*. Supongamos que tengo un array de atributos con un valor indeterminado, como puedo hacer que se genere la consulta de forma dinámica dependiendo del número de elementos que tenga el array attributes.

```
    $product = Product::wherehas('attributes', function ($q){
        $q->where('attribute_id', $attribute[0]);
    })->wherehas('attributes', function ($q){
        $q->where('attribute_id', $attribute[1]);
    })->get();
```

Ejemplo de consulta con tres elementos en el array attributes

```
    $product = Product::wherehas('attributes', function ($q){
        $q->where('attribute_id', $attribute[0]);
    })->wherehas('attributes', function ($q){
        $q->where('attribute_id', $attribute[1]);
    })->wherehas('attributes', function ($q){
        $q->where('attribute_id', $attribute[2]);    
    })->get();
```

¿Puedo utilizar algún tipo de bucle for para generar la consulta dependiendo del número de elementos en el array attributes?

Answer (score 1):

No uses `where()` usa `whereIn()`, donde podrás pasar tu array de datos para un mismo campo directamente.

Por ejemplo, si tienes un array de nombres de usuario:

```
$names = ['Foo', 'Baz'];
$users = User::whereIn('name', $names)->get();
```

*O con Query builder:*

```
$names = ['Foo', 'Baz'];
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('name', $names)->get();
```

Pero si tuvieras, sus IDs en lugar de otro atributo, puedes usar directamente el método `find()`, que admite tanto una ID como un array con las mismas:

```
$ids = [1,2,7,9];
$users = User::find('name', $ids);
```

Comment: Siguiendo tu ejemplo en mi caso necesitaría los usuarios que tuviesen el nombre foo y baz, los dos nombres